# Animated fish tank

Tags: javascript

I am working on this animated fish tank I got one of the fish to move I just can't figure out why the other 2 aren't moving. If someone can give me a hint onto where i might be screwing up or a web site that might help me. I have been looking all over and can't find nothing on this animated fish. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Fish tank</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS
var fish1Position = 0;
horizontal = new Array(50);
var fillPosition = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    horizontal[i] = fillPosition;
    fillPosition += 10;
 }
function fish1Swim() {
    document.getElementById("fish1").style.left = horizontal[fish1Position] + "px";
    ++fish1Position;
    if (fish1Position == 49)
            fish1Position = 0;
}
function startSwimming() {
    setInterval("fish1Swim()",100);
}
// STOP HIDING FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS -->

 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="startSwimming();">
 <p><span id="fish1" style=
 "position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px"><img src="fish1.gif" alt="Image of a fish"   /></span></p>
<p><span id="fish2" style=
"position:absolute; righy:10px; top:120px"><img src="fish2.gif" alt="Image of a fish" /></span></p>
<p><span id="fish3" style=
"position:absolute; left:10px; top:220px"><img src="fish3.gif" alt="Image of a fish" /></span></p>


 </body>
 </html>
```

I dont know how to get the other two fish going does anyone have a web site or something that will explain it to me

Comment: whats righy? [filling 15 chars]

Comment: ok i fix it i made it go back to the left and just switch the 2 and 3 around

Comment: Please replace `setInterval("fish1Swim()",100);` with `setInterval(fish1Swim, 100);` - using the `eval`-style arguments is **extremely discouraged**.

Comment: "<!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS"? You're worried about Netscape 2 and friends? In 2011? It doesn't work anyway, since you are using XHTML. http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/

Comment: alt="Image of a fish"? Go read http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html

Comment: Thank you david for explaning that i guess i am still learning the old ways

Comment: I dont know how to get the other two fish going does anyone have a web site or something that will explain it to me

Comment: `document.write("This one has a little star; this one has a little car.  My, what a lot of fish there are!");
alert("Blub blub blub.  Fish2 and fish3 are dead.");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're only animating fish1 in your script.

You need to have a fish2Swim and fish3Swim; better yet a function called fishSwim where you pass the number of the fish in question.

I would make something like this:

```
function fishSwim(fishNumber) {
document.getElementById("fish"+fishNumber).style.left = horizontal[fishPos[fishNumber] + "px";
++fishPos[fishNumber];
if (fishPos[fishNumber] == 49)
        fishPos[fishNumber] = 0;
}
```

So you would need to create an array Fish positions (called "fishPos" where the index would be the number of the fish. Feel free to ask me anything more about this :)

Comment: I edited my question to include a code snippet which maybe helpful to you

Comment: var fishSwim = new Array fish[0] =fish1.jpg  fish[1] = fish2.jpg  fish[2] = fish3.jpg then do the function? or am I wrong

Comment: ok the book i have that i am learning from is javascript and the chapter is dynmaic HTML(DHTML) and in my book it dont explain how to do this. I am so lost and confused about this that i am trying everything i know how to use and the fishes still aint swimming.